# Wordpress page layout goes bad when I pass google analytics parameters

Tags: css, wordpress, parameter-passing

I have the latest wordpress 3.9.0 installed on this URL: http://www.adlabsimagica.com

While the pages and the website is working fine, the page layout breaks out when I pass GA utm parameters.

To understand the exact nature of the problem you can see this URL (I can't post two links with and without, since I'm new and am allowed to post just one link)

http://www.adlabsimagica.com/summer-fest/?utm_source=idiva&utm_medium=innovation&utm_campaign=SummerFest&utm_content=banners

If you take out the parameters from the link, it opens fine, but with the parameters the layout breaks.

Can you help me identify why this is happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: I removed the Google Analytics tag since this is not related to GA - the layout breaks with arbitrary parameters as well.

Comment: Looks like an additional widget is being pulled when you have arbitrary parameters - if it isn't needed remove it from your wordpress widget section? (or stick it in the inactive area?)

Comment: Like @Aravona says the widget is the problem post the widget code and we can sort it ;)